# unable to create a new feature file in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I'm unable to create a new feature file. There is no option called files while on new. Can anyone please help me with this? I have installed all the required cucumber plugins
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can always click the 'Other...' option in File > New to see everything that you can create. A plain new file is in the 'General' section of the Other menu.

You are getting a smaller than usual list in the File > New menu because you have the Debug perspective open rather than the Java perspective. The New menu varies depending on the active perspective.

You can use 'Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective' to change what the New menu shows in each perspective.